# Laravel 4 package from private repository: ServiceProvider not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I created a package for Laravel 4 that worked properly when used in development in *workbench* but when I install it with Composer it keeps returning me the error `Class 'Myvendor\Mypackage\MypackageServiceProvider' not found`.

There is a particularity with my package which is that the name of my classes sources are different from the name of my package. Usually they are the same.

```
vendor/
    Houle/
        laravel-dynamite/
            src/
                Fhoule/
                    Dynamite/
                        DynamiteServiceProvider.php
```

I know that it can work because Laravel work's this way too.

```
vendor/
    laravel/
        framework/
            src/
                Illuminate/
```

And the property *PSR-0* of my package *composer.json* seems to be properly configured:

```
"name": "Houle/laravel-dynamite",
...
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.0",
    "illuminate/support": "4.0.x"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "src/migrations",
        "src/controllers",
        "src/models"
    ],
    "psr-0": {
        "Fhoule\\Dynamite": "src/"
    }
},
...
```

How I created my package:

- Created the package with Artisan.
- Maked it work properly in workbench directory
- Pushed to private Bitbucket repo
- Installed new instance of Laravel
- Changed *composer.json* configuration to install my package (from private repository)

  ```
  "name": "laravel/laravel",
  ...
  "require": {
      "laravel/framework": "4.0.*",
      "Houle/laravel-dynamite": "2.0.1"
  },  
  "repositories": [{
      "type": "package",
      "package": {
          "name": "Houle/laravel-dynamite",
          "version": "2.0.1",
          "source": {
              "url": "git@bitbucket.org:Houle/laravel-dynamite.git",
              "type": "git",              
              "reference": "v2.0.1"
          }
      }
  }],
  ...
  ```
- Added my package Service Provider to app/config/app.php:

  ```
  'providers' => array(
      'Fhoule\Dynamite\DynamiteServiceProvider',
  )
  ```

That's where my application return the error `Class 'Fhoule\Dynamite\DynamiteServiceProvider' not found`.

What could be my issue?

Comment: Did you run ```php artisan dump-autoload``` ?

Comment: It's not necessary after executing `composer install` or `update`, but yes I tried it.

Comment: Ok, but actually, it is necessary to run artisan's dump-autoload if you are using workbench as it does more than the composer dump-autoload.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found my problem, it hadn't nothing to do with the way I named my vendor, package and classes.

It was that in my `composer.json` (root of the project), I set my repository type to `package` but like the Composer documentation states the type [package](http://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#package-2) is for packages that don't support Composer. That's why Composer wasn't updating my `autoload_classmap.php` file.

So if you want to use a [private repository](http://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#using-private-repositories) (like at Bitbucket or GitHub) you need to set the type of the repository to `git`:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    ...
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.0.*",
        "houle/laravel-dynamite": "dev-master"
    },  
    "repositories": [{
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git@bitbucket.org:Houle/laravel-dynamite.git"       
    }],
    ...
}
```

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

The `composer.json` in your package (Package found in BitBucket) needs to specify the `PSR-0` Autoloading component, rather than the `composer.json` file in your top-level Laravel project.

Can you show us the composer.json file for your repo in the private repository?

Comment: The content of my package `composer.json` is the first code snippet that I put in my question.